# TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__' (simple issue)

Tags: python

I'm a newbie on Python, and am struggling with a small piece of my code I just don't understand why it won't work.

I have list of lists, containing 3 numbers each. I  want to check if the first two numbers are the same for some of the lists. Why doesn't this work? What should I do to get it work?

```py
list=[[0, 4, 0], [1, 4, 0], [0, 3, 1], [0, 4, 1]]

sorted(list)

for i in range(len(list)-1):
  if list[i][0][1] == list[i+1][0][1]:
      print "overlap"
```

Comment: bear in mind your call to `sorted` discards its result, so has no impact on the code. Perhaps you meant `list.sort()`? This will sort the list in place (i.e. operate on the original and not return a sorted copy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access your matrix as if it would be a 3-dimensional matrix, however it's a 2-dimensional matrix.

Remove one of the indexes:

```py
list=[[0, 4, 0], [1, 4, 0], [0, 3, 1], [0, 4, 1]]

sorted(list)

for i in range(len(list)-1):
    if list[i][0:2] == list[i + 1][0:2]:
        print "overlap"
```

As @Dunes pointed out, the slice operator allows you to compare the required items of your list (check out [understanding python slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation) for details).

Comment: I think this is nearly what OP wants. They want to check the first two elements. So slicing to get them would be a good idea. eg. `list_[0:2]`.

Comment: True, didn't see that in the question, I'll update my answer.

Comment: thank you! This really helped me out, i've been struggling with this for hours but this [0:2] syntax is perfect for what I need.

Comment: Also, I had to sort the list in another way to make it work. But without errors, I can find my way.

Comment: See my comment on the question with regard to why that call to sorted is useless. I think the op allude to the same issue above.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need that extra `[1]`.

`list[i]` accesses the inner list, e.g. `[0, 4, 0]`

`list[i][0]` accesses the 1st element of that list: e.g. `0`

Also, please don't use built-in names as names for your variables as the built-in (`list` in our case) will no longer be accessible by that name.

Comment: This isn't entirely what op wants. OP wants to see overlap printed because there are two lists that start with `[0, 4, ...]` (as opposed to three lists that start with `0`. It would also help to explain why you shouldn't use builtin names (because you can use `list` in type checking, or as a constructor or as a base class for inheritance, and overwriting the `list` name breaks that).

Comment: @Dunes thanks for the feedback, I'll keep this in mind for future answers.